# change background color of pre-built angular material theme

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-material

I'm using the pre-built purple-green angular material pre-built theme with .css.  I'd like to use a white background but can't seem to change from the dark grey background.  I've tried removing class="mat-app-background" in the body tag of my index.html, but no impact.  Do I need to move to .scss to make this change?

Thanks

Pete

Answer (score 0):

```
element {
background: white !important;
}
```

If nothing else you have tried works, maybe try this one. It will override all previous styling rules for the specific property.